# USB 2.0 Isolation on ULPI bus

Tags: usb, isolation

I have a USB3318C phy, I would like to isolate the digital signals between the phy and the microprocessor the interface at the full 480MPbs. How could I provide galvanic isolation on the UPLI interface?

The UPLI interface runs at 60MHz, it has 8 Data lines that can be bidirectional. So, Gavanic isolation on a 60MHz bus.

Comment: I believe, there are dedicated ICs for USB isolation.

Comment: Not for USB 2.0 High speed, if you want the full 480Mbps there are  no isolators that work at that speed. All of the isolators available use a scheme like this PHY<->FPGA<->Digital isolator<->FPGA<->PHY. I want to do this UPROC<->Isolator <->Phy

Comment: Why isolate the complicated 8 data line bus instead of the pseudodifferential single lane USB2.0? Gut feeling:if *you* didn't find an IC, the "simplest" solution might be detangling the bidirectional bus with an FPGA on both sides of the isolation...

Comment: No, because I don't have that topology, you can isolate the phy and the UPLI interface, how do you isolate a bidrectional bus?

Comment: If I have to I'll use two unidirectional isolators, I'd prefer bidirectional

Comment: Depending on your need you may actually find it more economical to put something like an entire raspberry pi in the same galvanic domain as the USB device and delegate entire tasks to it via Ethernet or WiFi

Comment: Tried that option, built one, team didn't want to use it

Comment: Isn't it a shopping question? I believe I saw some isolators in some oscilloscope schematics, isolating ADC section from digital FIFO...but they were unidirectional.

Comment: Also, did you check the related links provided by Stack Exchange? Did you check products by https://intona.eu/en/products/ ?

Comment: "how do you isolate a bidrectional bus?" You spit the bus into two unidirectional ones, just as you already mentioned, {FPGA<->Digital isolator<->FPGA}. ULPI turn-around times might be a problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found is to use ADUM120N (or there are others that are wider than two signals.)

[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM120N_121N.pdf

You need a lot of them for the 14 signals on the UPLI bus (at least 7 if your running the ADUM120. But they get the job done.

They run at 150Mbps with a ~7ns propagation delay time (which is more than suitable for 60MHz.

Comment: There are some nice 6-channel ones (e.g. Silabs SI8661BB-B-IU), so two 6-ways and a 2-way (or three 6's with signals to spare) should do nicely.

Comment: Yeah, analog has a few also, but I don't have those in my library (yet). The SI ones are good to know about

Comment: If you use Eagle, [here's](https://gist.github.com/TCWORLD/6d56ad9b8b6b26bafb51848ec8a4792a) my Silicon labs library with some of the isolators in it.

Comment: Sadly I mainly use altium, but I do use Eagle at home on occasion so I'll look into that.